# logwatch for windows

Tags: windows, jboss

I have a need to be alerted via email of error messages in our JBoss logs.  JBoss is running on a Windows 2008 server.  I'm familiar with logwatch utilities on Linux, but I haven't found a well supported solutions for Windows.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Also I'd like to steer away from something like rsync'ing logs to a Linux log server which would run Linux log analysis scripts.  We'd like to keep the number of servers in our environment as low as possible.  Thank you!

Comment: You should consider to accept more answers on your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use log4j SMTP appender. The details of configuration are described [here](https://community.jboss.org/thread/171398)